# Sms icon presented on top notification bar - android

Tags: android, notifications, sms

Can someone suggest me which resource from Android should I use in order to present graphically incoming sms in notification bar, in the same look  & feel as Android does?

I use **android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email** while building a notification object, but it looks a little smaller, than default used by the system.

```
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx).setAutoCancel(true).setVibrate(vibration).setOngoing(false)
.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email, 1).setTicker(message).setContentText(message).setContentTitle(incomingNumber).setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
.setContentIntent(intent).build();
```

Shall I consider using setLargeIcon instead of setSmallIcon on the builder?

Comment: `setLargeIcon` is for the icon displayed on the left when the status bar is pulled down. See the diagram [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#NormalNotify). Maybe have a look at using the [Action Bar Icon Pack](http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html#action-bar-icon-pack).

Comment: I forgot to mention that I would like to do it on Android 2.3.6.

Comment: Perhpas you've already seen this but here's the [sizing guide for 2.3.x](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar.html#size9), which says "Status bar icons may vary in width, but only minimally." However, if it's noticeably different from the other status bar icons try downloading the Action Bar Icon Pack I linked to above and read [Providing Density-Specific Icon Sets](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html#icon-sets).